# host exception in .htaccess for http to https redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have defined the following code in my **`.htaccess`** file, how do I make an exception for **`http://mydomian.com`** to **not be redirected to https** ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

(Please note that somewhere on my site I'm loading **`http://mydomian.com`** via iFrame and on that website it doesn't have the https working properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude **www.mydomain.com** you can use the following RewriteCondition :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$
```

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```